# App Crash, no idea why

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports

I trying to figure out why my App crashes sometimes on costumers devices. It doesnt matter if the device is jailbreaked or not. My App is from the AppStore. The other crashlogs are nearly the same although their crashed threads are different.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         [the APP] [296]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/06DF5BC5-F9C2-49EE-B2D5-5979C09B51A2/[the APP].app/[the APP]
Identifier:      [the APP]
Version:         3.3.0
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-22 15:15:18 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xbbadbeef
Crashed Thread:  7

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c39004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x353673f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x353660f1 __CFRunLoopRun + 825
3   CoreFoundation                      0x352e94a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x352e936d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   GraphicsServices                    0x36f85439 GSEventRunModal + 137
6   UIKit                               0x32df5cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
7   [the APP]                           0x0000b549 main (main.m:20)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c393a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3422cbc9 _dispatch_mgr_wakeup + 1

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c490d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   WebCore                             0x311454ef _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 215
2   WebCore                             0x311a4173 _ZL19SendDelegateMessageP12NSInvocation + 707
3   WebKit                              0x3507ad87 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 119
4   CoreFoundation                      0x35395a83 ___forwarding___ + 667
5   CoreFoundation                      0x352f0650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
6   WebKit                              0x350816a1 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDecidePolicyForNavigationAction(void (WebCore::PolicyChecker::*)(WebCore::PolicyAction), WebCore::NavigationAction const&, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr) + 221
7   WebCore                             0x3120b8b9 WebCore::PolicyChecker::checkNavigationPolicy(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WTF::PassRefPtr, void (*)(void*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr, bool), void*) + 873
8   WebCore                             0x3120ae4d WebCore::FrameLoader::loadWithDocumentLoader(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr) + 913
9   WebCore                             0x312092b9 WebCore::FrameLoader::load(WebCore::DocumentLoader*) + 169
10  WebCore                             0x312091e5 WebCore::FrameLoader::load(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::SubstituteData const&, bool) + 241
11  WebKit                              0x350b3f5f -[WebFrame _loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:unreachableURL:] + 1119
12  WebKit                              0x350b3797 -[WebFrame _loadHTMLString:baseURL:unreachableURL:] + 79
13  WebKit                              0x350b37bb -[WebFrame loadHTMLString:baseURL:] + 31
14  WebCore                             0x311950b5 HandleRunSource + 365
15  CoreFoundation                      0x35367ad3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
16  CoreFoundation                      0x35367335 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 365
17  CoreFoundation                      0x35366045 __CFRunLoopRun + 653
18  CoreFoundation                      0x352e94a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
19  CoreFoundation                      0x352e936d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
20  WebCore                             0x311e8ca3 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 403
21  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c39004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x353673f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3536612b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x352e94a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x352e936d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x34e22bb9 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6   Foundation                          0x34e22a81 -[NSThread main] + 73
7   Foundation                          0x34eb6591 __NSThread__main__ + 1049
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49570 __select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c39004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x353673f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3536612b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x352e94a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x352e936d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   YouTube                             0x33e336c9 -[YTImageLoader(Internal) _startLoader] + 245
6   Foundation                          0x34e22a81 -[NSThread main] + 73
7   Foundation                          0x34eb6591 __NSThread__main__ + 1049
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 7 Crashed:
0   WebCore                             0x311454e2 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 202
1   WebCore                             0x3114540f WebThreadLock + 55
2   UIKit                               0x32e5537b -[UIWebTiledView layoutSubviews] + 43
3   UIKit                               0x32e5534b -[UIWebDocumentView layoutSubviews] + 127
4   UIKit                               0x32dcaf37 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 183
5   CoreFoundation                      0x352f21fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
6   QuartzCore                          0x321c2aa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 217
7   QuartzCore                          0x321c26bd CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 217
8   QuartzCore                          0x321c6843 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 227
9   QuartzCore                          0x321c657f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315
10  QuartzCore                          0x3220dd01 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 37
11  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x327490ff _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 171
12  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32748d7b _pthread_exit + 123
13  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3275a0f3 pthread_exit + 31
14  Foundation                          0x34e3237b +[NSThread exit] + 11
15  Foundation                          0x34eb65af __NSThread__main__ + 1079
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0xffffffff     r1: 0x00001100     r2: 0x2ffc850c     r3: 0x00000000 
    r4: 0xbbadbeef     r5: 0x00000000     r6: 0x0054b000     r7: 0x2ffc8b4c 
    r8: 0x0ca32800     r9: 0x3399fc2c    r10: 0x2ffc8be4    r11: 0x2ffc8ebc 
    ip: 0x3ee8e270     sp: 0x2ffc8b40     lr: 0x35790fef     pc: 0x32c7f4e2 
  cpsr: 0x60000030 

Binary Images:
[cut cause of char limit]
```

I have no idea what happend, anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you send messages to UI objects from a background thread, which is forbidden.

Thread 7 crashed with a stack trace into UIView's layout mechanism. The fact that thread 7 is in this code probably results from a `setNeedsLayout` or some other method being sent from this background thread.

Comment: but the problem is, the app crashed not always just in some rare cases

Comment: ... which is typical behavior for concurrency problems.

Answer (score 3):

I think web view finished loading and trying to reload view but view controller was poped and released,you need to add this in viewWillDisappear method:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([webView isLoading]) {
        [webView stopLoading];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The project that I am on sees a similar exception for a WinTel based GWT App running on the WebKit.  It has been determined that this particular problem only occurs when the WebKit runs out of memory.